# Minimum distance between two given curves

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometry, algebra-precalculus, maxima-minima

> Let $f(x)=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n} {(r+2)x^{2r}}$ and $g(x)=ax^2+\cos^2b+\sin b$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}$; $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$. If $d(n,a,b)$ represents shortest distance between curves $y=f(x)$ and $y=g(x)$ for given values of $n,a,b$; then
> $\hbox{(A)}\quad d(2019,2020,b)=\frac34\,\forall b\in\mathbb{R}$
> $\hbox{(B)}\quad d(n,-2018,b)=\frac34\,\forall b\in\mathbb{R},\,
> n\in\mathbb{N}$
> $\hbox{(C)}\quad d(n,a,b)=\frac34\,\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\,
> a,b\in\mathbb{R}$
> $\hbox{(D)}\quad d(2020,a,b)=\frac34\,\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R}$

I have tried simplyfying the two curves but nothing seems to be eminent wrt to the options given. Pls help.

Comment: Distance or vertical distance ?

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, if you show your attempt, we can directly address your problem.

Comment: There seems to be no correct option, IMO either way the distance should depend on $b$.